# Human (body) detection/recognition open source software?

Tags: images, image-processing, image-recognition, classification

I have like a trillion of images in my disk and want to classify them basically in 2 groups:

```
Those images which includes people (body shapes)
Those images which does not include people
```

Any desktop software - preferably Open Source - to help me on this?

Comment: Do you need a ready-to-use application, or a library to develop with? Does it need to work offline? Are cloud-based solutions OK?

Comment: Any type of software is fine, library or end-user, on-line or off-line, cloud or desktop.

Comment: Recognizing skin color would be a way to find out, but do you also want to recognize human shapes where no skin is visible? For instance a picture of a glove that presumably contains a hand, or a person in niqab.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes, think about those TV sports which does recognize players in the field.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) can detect faces and/or upright people and has examples of doing both. It can be used from C/C++/python and is open source & cross platform.

While it is not a ready made solution it can be used to construct such solutions as can be seen with the examples of [pedestrian detection](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/) & [face detection](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/11/creating-a-face-detection-api-with-python-and-opencv-in-just-5-minutes/) presumably you would need to do both to build a "people" detector.

OpenCV + Python & [Keras](https://keras.io/) can also be used to produce a "deep learning" classifier using [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) or [Theano](https://github.com/Theano/Theano)  where the computer teaches itself how to categorise images and there are some pre-trained models available which may be able to classify your images for you, see [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/20/imagenet-vggnet-resnet-inception-xception-keras/).

The above resources should enable you to create a script that will do what you need.

Disclamer: While most of the links above point to a single online resource that has a commercial element, *training*, that is that I am a fan because I find it a great resource not because I have any financial interest in the site or any of the services offered.

Comment: The asker wants "Any desktop software". Does OpenCV fit this requirement? If yes please tell us the name of the executable and how to make it detect human bodies, thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul the above is certainly software that runs on the desktop and is open source additional information added to allow the OP to perform the task as requested.